# replace texts between specified tag in given string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

what is the best way to replace text between tag [[ text ]] with for example "X" using regex |

for example:

```
this [[is]] my text [[new text]]
```

and as a result I would like to have:

```
this X my text X
```

I have triend with something like that:

```
string pattern = @"\[\[(.*)\]\]";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "this [[is]] my text [[new text]]";
string pattern = @"\[\[.+?\]\]";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "X");
```

**EDIT**

> what if I want to iterate through each matches

```
string pattern = @"\[\[(.+?)\]\]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                   .ToList();
```

or are you looking something like that

```
string pattern = @"\[\[(.+?)\]\]";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, 
                           pattern, 
                           m=>String.Join("",m.Groups[1].Value.Reverse()));
```

which will return:

this **si** my text **txet wen**

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead

```
"\[\[(.[^\]])*\]\]"
```

And use the

```
rgx.Replace(yourString, "x");
```